# Migrate Classes.FromAssembly of Castle Windsor Library To Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, autofac

I have register this in castle windsor. what will be alternat code for this in AutoFac?

```
//Transient
        context.IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
            Classes.FromAssembly(context.Assembly)
                .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
                .BasedOn<ITransientDependency>()
                .WithService.Self()
                .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                .LifestyleTransient()
            );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(context.Assembly)
       .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ITransientDependency)))
       .AsSelf()
       .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().Where(i => t.Name.Contains(i.Name.Substring(1))));
```

You don't have to use the `.InstancePerDependency()` method to specify that you registration will be transient because this is the default in *Autofac*

Comment: I have this class in other dll which is not part of interfaces dll ... so how can I get assemblies?

Comment: does `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` or `Assembly.Load("xxx')`  help you ?